# exit from all methods in an object in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, class, object, exit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to break outer cycle in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352120/how-to-break-outer-cycle-in-ruby)

say I have this code:

```
class A

  def initialize
    myMethod()
    print "This should not be printed"
  end

  def myMethod
    #here
  end

end

obj = A.new
print "This should be printed"
```

Is there any command that I can place instead of "#here" that would exit the 'obj' object and continue to the next statement? (print "This should be printed")

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to break outer cycle in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352120/how-to-break-outer-cycle-in-ruby), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988045

Answer (score 3, accepted):

throw/catch will do it:

```
class A

  def initialize
    catch :init_done do
      myMethod()
      print "This should not be printed"
    end
  end

  def myMethod
    throw :init_done
  end

end

obj = A.new
print "This should be printed"
```

Comment: this isn't exactely what I was hoping for but I've done a little research myself and it looks like there is no better way so thanks for the answer.