# How to skip outer loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to break outer cycle in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352120/how-to-break-outer-cycle-in-ruby)

```
array_1 = %W(http://www.abc.com www.xyz.com www.pqr.com)
array_2 = %W(www.abc.com www.exmple.com)
array_1.each do |a1|
  array_2.each do |a2|
    next if(a1.include?(a2))
  end
puts a1
end
```

I want to skip those entries which are present in array_2. Is there anyway I can skip printing a1 if condition is satisfied? Ruby doesn't have label like java and I want to skip outer loop. :(

Any help would be great

Comment: I don't think the question is duplicate; while the OP is indeed asking about how to break an outer cycle, refactoring seems the way to go.

Comment: @tokland code snippet works perfectly in my actual implementation. Thanks all for replying :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write:

```
array_1.each do |a1|
  next if array_2.any? { |a2| a1.include?(a2) }
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass lambda with `return` statement to `each` method instead of block. Lambda function will return value, not the method enclosing lambda.

```
array_1 = %W(http://www.abc.com www.xyz.com www.pqr.com)
array_2 = %W(www.abc.com www.exmple.com)
array_1.each(&lambda do |a1|
  array_2.each do |a2|
    return if(a1.include?(a2))
  end
  puts a1
end)
```

Comment: break will exit the current loop, but return will exit a function. so putting that in a function like Alex is a good way to do it. in other languages you'd be able to use the evil goto :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to mimic other languages, you can do something like this instead:

```
array_1.product(array_2).each do |a1, a2|
  next if(a1.include?(a2))
end
```

or, more idiomatic:

```
array_1.product(array_2).reject{ |a1, a2|
  a1.include?(a2)
}.each{ |a1, a2|
  # do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]Misread the input. This should be better. The any? method quits searching if one match is found.

```
array_1 = %W(http://www.abc.com www.xyz.com www.pqr.com)
array_2 = %W(www.abc.com www.exmple.com)

puts array_1.reject{|a1| array_2.any?{|a2| a1.include?(a2)} }
```

But if you insist in breaking out of a loop, there is `catch`and `throw`:

```
array_1.each do |a1|
  catch :its_in do
    array_2.each do |a2|
      throw :its_in if(a1.include?(a2))
    end
  puts a1
  end
end
```

Comment: substraction of arrays is a good idea, but look at the values, the OP really needs test inclusion, they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop

This might work:

```
busy = true
while busy
  array1.each do |a1|
    array2.each do |a2|

       busy = false
    end
  end
end
```