# ruby break double statement

Tags: ruby, loops, break

How to break double statement?

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

if a == 1
    if b == 2
        c = 5
        d = 6
        break
    end
end

puts c
puts d
```

Output

```
loop.rb:9: Invalid break
loop.rb: compile error (SyntaxError)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: The same question has already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352120/how-to-break-outer-cycle-in-ruby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't break from inside an `if`, you can only break from inside loops and blocks.

If what you're asking is how to break from two nested loops, you can use `catch` in combination with `throw`—these are not the same as try and catch in other languages.

```
catch(:stop) do
  while some_cond
    while other_cond
      throw :stop
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, you can always just set a flag or some such to tell the outer loop that it should break too.