# Return to Each Iterator from For Loop

Tags: ruby, for-loop, block

I was wondering if it is possible to return to an Each iterator in Ruby from within a for-loop placed within the block passed to Each.

```
def find member = ""

        productHash = {}

            #@entries is a hash, with both the keys and values being strings
            #the member parameter is a string

        @entries.each do |key, value|

            for i in 0...member.size

                if(key[i] != member[i])
                    next #the next keyword doesn't work...all it does is return to the for iterator.  I'm looking for a keyword that would return to the each iterator, and allow each to pass back in the next key-value pair.
                end

            end

            productHash[key] = value


        end

        productHash

end
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is this: the moment I see that a character in the member parameter doesn't match the corresponding character in a given key, I move on to the next key-value pair.

Comment: Why are you using a for loop? Why don't you do an each method with a block?

Comment: @jason328 How would that help?  The issue would still be the same I believe.  And the reason I'm using a for loop here is so that I can keep track of the index number for purposes of comparing to the corresponding character in the parameter "member".  I guess conceptually my question is whether any of the return statements (such as break, next, return) discriminate between a for-loop iterator and an each iterator.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Would using `each_with_index` help you at all?

Comment: What is `member`?  An array?

Comment: It looks like it. I suspect it's pseudo code as there is no way that method could work without some parameters added.

Comment: The reason your question is difficult to understand is that it makes a number of assumptions about data that aren't reflected
in how your code is structured:

1. `member`: this is either a hash or an array.
2. `@entries`: probably a hash, given the block arguments.
3. The `key` of each entry is another hash or array.
4. As it's written, your method doesn't care about the for loop; it's just going to return a duplicate of `@entries`.

Be more explicit about what you want to do. Provide examples for your variables, and what you expect as the outcome (or better yet, a test)

Comment: I added in clarification in comments within the code.  The Member parameter is a string, and the keys and values are also strings (I apologize for not clarifying that earlier).  @jason328 the code was not pseudocode though.  Setting a default value to member was not necessary, although it definitely improves clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do some kind of comparison where if the key matches a particular prefix specified by `member` then you would make an assignment.

This code should be functionally similar:

```
def find(member = "")
  hash = { }

  @entries.each do |key, value|
    # Unless key begins with prefix, skip it.
    next unless (key[0, prefix.length] == prefix)

    hash[key] = value
  end

  hash
end
```

There's no official `goto` statement in Ruby, and many would argue this is a good thing, but it means that busting out of nested blocks can be a bit tricky.

Still, if you approach the problem in the right way, there's almost always a solution that's elegant enough.

**Update:**

To break out of nested loops, an approach might be:

```
list.each do |i|
  broken = false

  inner_list.each do |j|
    if (j > 10)
      broken = true
      break
    end
  end

  break if (broken)
end
```

Comment: thank you so much!  just to verify, is there no way to exit from within the for-loop to the each iterator in my code?

Comment: To be honest, nobody uses `for` in Ruby except people who've ever used Ruby before. The `each` iterator, or something else from Enumerable, is used instead. To kick out of two levels, `return` will usually do the trick if you can exit the method immediately. As an alternative, set a flag and `break`, then `break` again if that condition is set.

Comment: I've amended my answer with a short example of that.

Comment: this makes sense.  i guess my question conceptually boiled down to whether or not any of the keywords *return, break, and next* discriminated between a for-loop and the each method.  it looks like they don't, so setting a flag will always be necessary.

Comment: Yeah, they only affect the current loop context. Some other languages support a `break` that has an optional target label, but Ruby does not.

Comment: Using throw and catch is usually considered the correct way to break out of deeply nested loops, and even deeply nested method calls. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352120/how-to-break-outer-cycle-in-ruby

Comment: That's interesting, but I'd use that as a last-resort. Usually if you've dug a hole deep enough you need that to get out of it, the design of your logic should be simplified. In this case, it's massive overkill. Packaging this simple logic in a method that can call `return` is by far the most straight-forward and easily testable approach.