# call next on ruby loop from external method

Tags: ruby

in Ruby it's easy to tell loop to go to next item

```
(1..10).each do |a|
  next if a.even?
  puts a
end
```

result =>

```
1
3   
5
7
9
```

but what if I need to call next from outside of the loop (e.g.: method)

```
def my_complex_method(item)
  next if item.even?  # this will obviously fail 
end

(1..10).each do |a|
  my_complex_method(a)
  puts a
end
```

only solution I found and works is to use `throw` & `catch` like in SO question [How to break outer cycle in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352120/how-to-break-outer-cycle-in-ruby)

```
def my_complex_method(item)
  throw(:skip) if item.even? 
end

(1..10).each do |a|
  catch(:skip) do   
    my_complex_method(a)
    puts a
  end
end
```

My question is: anyone got any more niftier solution to do this ?? or is `throw/catch` only way to do this ??

Also what If I want to call `my_complex_method` not only as a part of that loop (=> don't throw :skip) , can I somehow tell my method it's called from a loop ?

Comment: You're really, *really* over thinking this. Return a value and invoke `next` conditionally based on the returned value. This is an *incredibly* common pattern in software, in virtually every language I've ever used. `throw`/`catch` have no place here.

Comment: I agree that for this example it's ridiculous, but I have a case where I need separation of loop and  method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You complex method could return a boolean, and then you compare on your loop like this:

```
def my_complex_method(item)
  true if item.even? 
end

(1..10).each do |a|
  next if my_complex_method(a)
  puts a
end
```

A simple approach, but different from the try catch one.

**UPDATE**

As `item.even?` already return a boolean value, you don't need the `true if item.even?` part, you can do as follow:

```
def my_complex_method(item)
  item.even? 
end
```

Comment: I'll go with this answer because it made me realize that `my_complex_method` in my real code can be written different way so this can be achieved (as well as did Meagar comment on my question)... but if anyone ever need to use functionality as I described in my qestion I would go with [Pritis answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17546856/473040) rather than with my `throw/catch` solution

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerator#next`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html#next-instance_method) and [`Enumerator#peek`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html#peek-instance_method) will be good option to goo :

```
def my_complex_method(e)
  return if e.peek.even? 
  p e.peek
end
enum = (1..5).each
enum.size.times do |a|
  my_complex_method(enum)
  enum.next
end
```

**Output**

```
1
3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to take actions on only some of values, based on value returned by `my_complex_method` you could use enumerators wisely:

```
(1..10).map { |a| [a, my_complex_method(a)] }.each do |a, success|
  puts a if success
end
```

<del>You could define method accepting block and take some action in this block based on success or failure there:

    (1..10).each do |a|
      my_complex_method { |success| next if success }
    end

Thanks to scoping, you are able not to use `catch`/`throw`, and call `next` based on processing status.</del>

Comment: As far as I can tell the first method doesn't work - the `next` isn't passed through to `each`

Comment: Ah, you are right -- `next` here refers to yield defined in `my_complex_method`...