# Call next for outer loop from within a method

Tags: ruby, loops

Is it possible to call next from within a method for an outer loop:

**bot.rb**

```
while Option.daemon_active?(daemon: "bot")
  .....
  Trade.market_order
  ....
end
```

**trade.rb**

```
class Trade
  def self.market_order
     ... complex code ...
     response = exchange.market_sell
     next if response["state"] == false # This fails. This should start new iteration of while in bot.rb
  end
end
```

There is quite similar question, but it doesn't seem to suit me: [call next on ruby loop from external method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546516/call-next-on-ruby-loop-from-external-method)

Comment: What’s wrong with `next unless Trade.market_order` in the while block?

Comment: agreed with @mudasobwa the `Bot` should not be controlled via `Trade`, it is simply not its responsibility and increases coupling which usually should be avoided (hard to follow path of execution, hard to refactor, `Trade` may break if `Bot` changes etc.)

Comment: Thank you @mudasobwa. Good comment, although right now market order is much more complicated than I shown here, there are lot of checks and all of them need to call next at some point. Maybe I need to simplify it

Comment: `return false` everywhere you need the next iteration or use @sawa’s approach with `catch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You should use `throw` and `catch`.

bot.rb

```
while Option.daemon_active?(daemon: "bot")
  catch(:foo) do
    ...
    Trade.market_order
    ...
  end
end
```

trade.rb

```
class Trade
  def self.market_order
    ...
    response = exchange.market_sell
    throw :foo if response["state"] == false
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems you are overdesigned this. `response["state"] ? response : nil` as a return value from `market_order` and `next unless market_order` do the trick in a way more readable manner.

Comment: @mudasobwa That is not equivalent to the OP's code. `false` and `nil` are different.

Comment: Occasionally it is. OMG. `response["state"] != false ? response : false`.

Comment: `next unless market_order` may work, but that is not what OP asked. I agree with you that this may be an XY-question.

Comment: This is exactly what OP asked. Furthermore, this is exactly what your code does.