# Rails - conditional deliver_now based on the content returned by the mailer method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**How can I `deliver_now` conditionally based on the content of the data returned by the mailer method?**

I have a Mailer that is sent via a loop through a list of users, like so:

```
users.each do |u|
   AbcMailer.with(user_id: u.user_id).abc_report.deliver_now
end
```

The *list* of users that should receive the mailer (`users` in the loop) lives in ActiveRecord, and all the users' actual data lives in an external MySql DB.

The `abc_report` method in the `AbcMailer` class makes some queries to the MySql DB and returns a bunch of info for each user, which is then inserted into an html.erb email template, and delivered now.

My issue is that I need to only deliver to *some* of those users, because in the DB, one of the pieces of info that comes back is whether the user is active or not. **So I would like to only `deliver_now` if the user has active = 1.** But I can't find any examples of unchaining these methods to do what I want.

When I just do `AbcMailer.with(user_id: u.user_id).abc_report`, what it returns is actually the filled-out html.erb template already. When I do `AbcMailer.with(user_id: u.user_id)` by itself, it returns `#<ActionMailer::Parameterized::Mailer:0x00007fdd43eb5528>`.

**Things I've Tried**

I tried inserting a `return if user["Active"] == 0` in the `abc_report` method but that obviously killed the entire loop rather than skipping to the next item, so I'm working under the assumption that the skip has to happen with a `next` in the actual loop itself, not in an external method being called.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546516/call-next-on-ruby-loop-from-external-method) which seems like a great solution in a plain Ruby context but because in this case, `abc_report` is automatically filling out and returning the `AbcMailer` html.erb template...I'm stumped on how I would get it to just return a boolean without killing the whole loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have `active` field of `boolean` type in `users` table and you want to send the emails to all `active` users.

```
users.each do |u|
   AbcMailer.with(user_id: u.user_id).abc_report.deliver_now if u.active
end
```

you can add any other condition on this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to *user.rb*

```
scope :active, -> {
  where(active: 1)
}
```

Now in your mailer

```
Users.active.each do |user|
 AbcMailer.with(user_id: user.user_id).abc_report.deliver_now
end
```

This way you have to get less data from the database, resulting in a faster query.