# Is there a Way To Exit Two Loops by Single Command In Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops

Here is the  Sample code,

```
while true
   while true
      exit all loops when condition true
   end
end
```

Can someone tell me if is it possible here to exit first loop when second loop breaks, but then I want to use only one break command and no raise.

Comment: Wrap them in a method and return from that. Or use throw/catch.

Comment: Ya it's a good idea, but is there any other way to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean? There are two other ways right there.

Comment: I don't want to raise any exception. I want to know any other logics to do this.

Comment: throw/catch is not exception handling. You confused them with raise/rescue.

Comment: Ya i agree my mistake. Is there a way to do this without raise and more than one break . Also i agree the answer you gave is very good. But i am looking, is there any other way to solve this problem. I mean any ruby command can do this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you want the functionality (breaking out of several loops), you have it in my answer. throw/catch is such command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to break outer cycle in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352120/how-to-break-outer-cycle-in-ruby) ...Maybe I should have Googled for duplicates before failing at answering. Oops.

Comment: Ya you are right , it is the best solution. @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know what's better than using only one `break`? Not using any at all! :)

Little-used `throw/catch` is good here

```
catch(:done) do 
  while cond1
    while cond2
      throw :done if condition
    end
  end
end
```

For more information, see the docs on [`throw`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-throw) and [`catch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-catch).

Comment: ...Gosh darnit, you just _had_ to write that up in the time I spent not reading the post, didn't you?

Comment: I didn't know throw/catch was distinct from exceptions until... oh, about three minutes ago. I'm too used to Java.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so apparently boolean flags are a no-go. Oops.

The other thing that pops to mind is catching an error, but you said you don't want to do that, or wrap it in a method and return. Honestly, there doesn't seem to be a way, but here's the simplest I could come up with:

```
catch (:exit) do
    while true
        while true
            throw :exit if condition
        end
    end
end
```

You could *also* throw an exception, but that seems dirty. Here's the code to do it, though:

```
begin
    while true
        while true
            raise "Exiting loops" if condition
        end
    end
rescue
    #Code to go after the loop
end
```

Lastly, you could wrap the whole thing in a method and return from that method:

```
def my_descriptive_method_name()
    while true
        while true
            return if condition
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ...Nope, I didn't. Lemme figure that out.

Comment: There, now my answer is functionally identical to Sergio's because he was faster at typing it up, and I was busy looking at the Edit Post screen, not the answers. Well, it's got some extra stuff, too.

Comment: See, now you have more stuff :)